# JQuery to select child element(not sure if selectable if not directly under parent)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="A">ABC
<div class="B">bcs</div>
<div class="C"></div>
<select id="D" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="123">123</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I would like to test to select option and change its value

```
jQuery(function () {
var A = document.getElementById("A");
var B = A.getElementsByTagName("select";)
B.getElementsByTagName("option").val('123');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ddj6P/

The code looks fine, but yet not working.

Comment: You seem to be mixing DOM API (`getElementsByTagName`) with jQuery (`.val`). This cannot work (like this). But the immediate error is a different one: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`. Look at the third line in your code and [learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Answer (score 3):

You were close.

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array, so you want to grab the 0th index.  Also, you want to set the value on the select, not the option

```
var B = A.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
B.value = '123';
```

Also note the syntax error I corrected, as Felix pointed out in his comment.

---

Or, since you're already using jQuery, why not just do:

```
jQuery('#A select').val('123');
```

Comment: sorry actually the code is meant for multiple select fields under the same div id, so what will the [0] value be if so?

Comment: If there are multiple selects, then [0] will give you the first one.  You can either loop through all of them manually, or the jQuery sample I put up will update all of them in one shot.

Comment: what if i want to change class of the child div instead?

Comment: jQuery has addClass, removeClass.  You'd probably use one of those depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use -

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('select option:contains("123")').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
  var A = $('#A');
  var B = A.children('#D');
  B.children('option:selected').val('123');
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/Ddj6P/2/)